# Unir varios elementos contiguos de una lista solo bajo cierta condición

Tags: python

Partiendo de una lista:

```
lista = ['hola', 'xnhaces', 'xntal', 'adios', 'ciao', 'buenas', 
         'xnhoraes', 'xnpasa', 'xnhacemos', 'hastaluego', 'xnbien']
```

El objetivo sería obtener una lista donde se unan los elementos contiguos que empiezan por 'xn' y añadirlos al elemento inmediatamente anterior que no empieza por 'xn'.

Es decir, obtener:

```
['holaxnhacesxntal', 'adios', 'ciao', 'buenasxnhoraesxnpasaxnhacemos', 'hastaluegoxnbien']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo más sencillo es recorrer la lista hacia atrás, e ir guardando en una lista auxiliar todos los que encontremos que comienzan por `xn`, hasta llegar a uno que no (inclusive). Concatenamos el resultado de esa lista (hacia atrás) y tenemos así una de las palabras del resultado. Vamos añadiendo esas palabras a otra lista. Al final, damos la vuelta a la lista resultado.

```
lista = ['hola', 'xnhaces', 'xntal', 'adios', 'ciao', 'buenas', 
         'xnhoraes', 'xnpasa', 'xnhacemos', 'hastaluego', 'xnbien']

resultado = []
auxiliar = []
for palabra in reversed(lista):
  if palabra.startswith("xn"):
    auxiliar.append(palabra)
  else:
    auxiliar.append(palabra)
    resultado.append("".join(reversed(auxiliar)))
    auxiliar = []
print(list(reversed(resultado)))
```

```
['holaxnhacesxntal', 'adios', 'ciao', 'buenasxnhoraesxnpasaxnhacemos', 'hastaluegoxnbien']
```

Answer (score 0):

Sin duda la respuesta de @abulafia es la indicada, sin embargo estuve pensando una manera de solucionar el tema de forma alternativa. En **R** hay una función muy útil que "divide" una lista en múltiples listas, a partir de otra lista especial que define cada grupo a dividir. En tu caso dónde el ejemplo es:

```
lista = ['hola', 'xnhaces', 'xntal', 'adios', 'ciao', 'buenas', 
         'xnhoraes', 'xnpasa', 'xnhacemos', 'hastaluego', 'xnbien']
```

Los grupos para el `split` que en definitiva serían los grupos de concatenación de podrían definir así:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]
```

Con esta lista, el recorte final en sublistas quedaría así:

```
['hola', 'xnhaces', 'xntal']
['adios']
['ciao']
['buenas', 'xnhoraes', 'xnpasa', 'xnhacemos']
['hastaluego', 'xnbien']
```

Lo primer es armar esta lista de "recorte":

```
from itertools import accumulate

d  =  list(accumulate([0 if palabra.startswith("xn") else 1 for palabra in lista][:-1]+[0]))
print(d)

[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]
```

Y luego definimos una función de `split()` y la aplicamos a la lista original concatenando luego las palabras de cada grupo o sublista.

```
from itertools import compress
def split(x, f):
    count = max(f)+1
    return tuple(list(compress(x, (el == i for el in f))) for i in range(count)) [1:]

print(["".join(grupo) for grupo in split(lista, d)])

['holaxnhacesxntal', 'adios', 'ciao', 'buenasxnhoraesxnpasaxnhacemos', 'hastaluegoxnbien']
```